# developing facebook pages

Tags: facebook

can anyone give me some ideas as to where to start from for ***developing dynamic facebook tabs*** like  - 
http://www.facebook.com/AppStore?v=app_133863019976324&ref=ts
and 
http://www.facebook.com/Savings?v=app_4949752878

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Those are the "profile tabs" or "application tabs" of Canvas Applications

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs